# Getting an alert: "Gap_init:2" in Android device

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Dojo version :1.10.3 (ae6be82)
    Java 7
    MobileFirst platform Studio 7.0.0.00-20150907-1450
    Os:Ubuntu 14.4(64 bit)

After applying `iFix 7.0.0.0 MFPF-StudioP2-IF201509071450.zip` our adapter calls are failing, it is not connecting to the server. There is no error printed in console.log or messages.log nor trace.log.

The app is working fine in browser preview but getting an alert gap_init:2 in device.

Note: I recreated android environment and rebuild

Comment: Does it also happen in NEW project and application, or only in Your application?

Comment: Provide the LogCat log from Eclipse. That's the relevant log you need to look at.

Comment: Yes it happens with new project also.

Comment: Provide the LogCat lot from Eclipse. Mention on which devices you are testing.

Comment: 10-01 20:20:51.247: E/NONE(8623): [/apps/services/api/Sample/android/query] failure. state: 500, response: undefined
10-01 20:20:51.327: E/EmojiFactory_jni(8623): Failed to load libemoji.so: dlopen failed: library "libemoji.so" not found

Comment: You continue to fail to explain your issue - provide your project so that it could be debugged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: This is in fact not related to the Android Emulator, but to previewing the Android environment in the MobileFirst Console's MBS. This happens due to a regression and is taken care of in *APAR PI50036 CORDOVA "GAP_INIT:2" ERROR WHEN PREVIEWING ANDROID IN MBS*.

---

I am unable to confirm this.

The claim was that a new application fails to properly load, with Cordova-related errors.

I have used a newer iFix than yours: IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.0.0.00-20151001-0721, created a new project and application, added the Android environment, built the project and launched it in the Android Emulator (using Android 5.0.1) - the application successfully loaded without any errors.

I suggest for you to login to IBM Fix Central with your customer credentials and download the latest available 7.0 iFix, and try again.

Comment: ok and i will send you log files  ...
Thanks for sharing the valuable information and spending the time in doing so,

Comment: 10-01 20:20:51.247: E/NONE(8623): [/apps/services/api/Sample/android/query] failure. state: 500, response: undefined
10-01 20:20:51.327: E/EmojiFactory_jni(8623): Failed to load libemoji.so: dlopen failed: library "libemoji.so" not found

Comment: IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.0.0.00-20151001-0721 we dnt find with our customer credentials. we found latest one as iFix 7.0.0.0 MFPF-StudioP2-IF201509300707.zip

Comment: That's fine. In Fix Central you will find from either September 29th or 30th. That will do as well.

Comment: Facing Same problem after applying iFix 7.0.0.0 MFPF-StudioP2-IF201509300707.zip

Comment: Provide your project then. It's not happening here.

Comment: please provide your email id

Comment: Upload it to Dropbox.

Comment: I tested with your project as well. I only had to configure the correct host to connect to (I changed it in native project > assets > wlclient.properties), and point it to the correct database name, since I don't have yours...) and was able to get "success" alert. Check that you are connecting to the correct hostname.

Comment: (code is working fine before applied fix pack ) getting problem after applying fix pack, any steps to follow applying fix pack

Comment: I cannot help. Your project is working. Sorry. Try to delete the native folder